# split() doesn't work with only 1 value

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Is there a way to make `split()` to work with only one value?

If you change *data-ids* in the following code to a single string of `122` then split returns nothing and it should return 122.

https://jsfiddle.net/mghwscox/

```js
var ids = $('div').data('ids').split(',');

$(ids).each(function(key, value) {
 $('div').append('Value: ' + value + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ids="122,154,344"></div>
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted, care to elaborate? This is a good question that helps to demonstrate an important "gotcha" with retrieving values from data attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ids = $('div').data('ids').toString().split(',');

$(ids).each(function(key, value) {
    $('div').append('Value: ' + value + '<br>');
});
```

Notice that I added toString() in your ids declaration.

Comment: A short explanation as to why adding `.toString()` worked would probably be helpful to Alex

Comment: What does the "ids" line have to do with the issue?

Comment: Fair comment but... I'm not certain or qualified enough to know but can only speculate. i have had a similar problem before and resolved it this way. It appeared to be sane (ie not a crude solution) so I have kept it in mind.

Comment: I removed my comment about the ids. i thought the value of ids was going to be the "ID" tag of other input fields, I did not expect ids to be comma separated numbers.

Comment: Short and worked right a way. Who cares about the explanation? =)

Comment: I can help you out with that, @fiprojects. The reason `toString()` solves this problem is because when you're coercing values out of a data attribute, the JS interpreter is going to try it's best to figure out what the data type of that value is. When commas are included in a string, the interpreter sees the commas and decides "this is a string" - and therefore, `split()` will work correctly. When it's just a single number, whether or not you consider it to be a string, the interpreter determines that it's a number, which does not include the `split()` method.

Comment: I glad it worked but I agree with j08691 that knowing why is (almost) as important as knowing how.

Comment: Thanks @jeffdill2 and - that makes sense and your comments and epascarello comments remind me of reading something like this in the data() api page at some point.

Comment: @AlexG I would certainly hope that _you'd_ care. Having a "right" answer but not knowing why it's right is incredibly dangerous and doesn't help you to actually become a better developer. :-0

Comment: I agree with you again @JeffDill2 - I don't always understand the mechanics, but I always make sure that if I use/write code, that I can support it or at some point going forward it will surprise and bite.

Comment: @AlexG No one gets taught math by simply getting all the answers. In the same way, just because code works you still need to know *how* and *why* it works or else you'll make the same mistake again in the future even though the problem is the same.

Comment: h2ooooooo & jeffdill2: I disagree with you, knowing this information will not prevent from same mistake in the future.

Comment: @AlexG perhaps not, but if you don't value the importance of actually *understanding* the code that you're shipping, then I fear for the people at the receiving end of that code. :-/

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can store the value as an plain array.

```
<div id="source" data-ids="[122,154,344]"></div>
<script>
    var list = $("#source").data('ids');
    console.log(list.length); //3
</script>
```

A working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source" data-ids="[122,154,344]"></div>
<div id="target"></div>

<script>
    var list = $("#source").data('ids');
    $("#target").html(JSON.stringify(list) + " has " + list.length + " elements"); // 3
</script>
```

**note:** the reason your code fails with one number is because jQuery converts the one number into a `Number` object and 'Number' objects have no `split` method.

Answer (score 3):

data() tries to do a type conversion when it reads the data. So you have two choices.

You can use data() and have to use toString() to make sure you have a string.

```
var ids = $('div').data('ids').toString().split(',');
```

Other option is to not use data() and use attr() to read the value.

```
var ids = $('div').attr("data-ids").split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

When the users gives only one number it is taken as number and since split()  method does not exists for numbers, its gives error. And if you provide comma-separated value it is getting treated as string and hence works fine.

```js
var ids = $('div').data('ids');
console.log(ids,typeof ids);
ids = ids.toString().split(',');;

$(ids).each(function(key, value) {
 $('div').append('Value: ' + value + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ids="122"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to string before split

```
var ids = ($('div').data('ids')+'').split(',');


$(ids).each(function(key, value) {
    $('div').append('Value: ' + value + '<br>');
});
```